# how to display 24 hours in xAxis on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, highcharts

I have a dashboard that needs to display the total articles published in the chart.

my xAxis needs to show 12:00am - 12:00 pm - 12:00am

when the user hovers over the chart a tooltip should display the number of articles published per minute.

sample output  when hover

12:00am - 55 articles

12:01am - 60 articles

12:02am - 45 articles

and so on...

I am just new to Highcharts, series options still confuse me.

[Please click here to see the chart image I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXFZo.png)

here's what I have

```
 xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime' //ensures that xAxis is treated as datetime values
},

series: [{
  // number of articles published per minute
   data: [55,23,45,60,78,56],
    pointStart: Date.UTC(2021, 0, 1, 12, 0)
}]
}
```

I hope someone can help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `tickInterval` [API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.spline.pointInterval)

```
serie: {
  pointInterval: 12 * 3600 * 1000, // 12 hours interval
  ...
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/12fsg7wr/)